# Large File Upload Using HttpHandler or HttpModule?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, request, httphandler, httpmodule

I have a webform application. It required to be able to upload large file (100MB). I intended to use httpHandler and httpModule to split the file to **chunk**.

I also had a look at http://forums.asp.net/t/55127.aspx

But it is a very old post and I've seen some example on the internet using httpHandler.

e.g. http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/

I'm not sure httpModule is still better then httpHandler.

Since httpModule apples to the request of the whole application, and I just want it apply to specify page.

Can anybody explain the **shortcoming of httpHandler for large file upload** clearly (if it has)?
If you know a good example without flash/silverlight , could you post the link here? thx

Edit: Would Like to see some **Source Code** example.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @KamranPervaiz thx i've read that one. I prefer to view some source code example.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which has lot of features with many fallbacks and here how it is done.

This is the http handler code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web


Public Class upload : Implements IHttpHandler


    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim chunk As Integer = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
        Dim fileName As String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)

        Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)

        Dim uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads")
        Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
            Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        context.Response.Write("Success")
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Cannot find read to chunk part and seems plupload doesn't support HTML4, thx anyway.

Comment: it supports HTML4.from the API documentation http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.runtimes.Html4.html

Comment: Out of interest why is the buffer set to the input stream length minus 1?