# how to send a large file to Request Stream in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, rest

I want to send large files >800 mb to cassansdra storage.But I am getting
**System.OutOfMemoryException** .

Please find the code below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

int len;
while ((len = fileToUpload.File.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) >0)
{
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    requestStream.Flush();
}
return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Please suggest me which part of the code needs improvement?

fileToUpload is the exact stream of 800 MB from UI.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: I get the exception at requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
after some 500 MB is done

Answer (score 1):

By default the maximum size of file uploaded using an HttpRequest is 4 MB (4096 KB). If you have access to code on the receiving end you can increase this in web.config although I have never tested it for 800+ MB files :) Keep in mind that Asp.Net will time-out any request after 180 seconds so that practically limits the size of file you can upload.

```
<httpRuntime
  executionTimeout="110" 
  maxRequestLength="4096" />
```

[Uploading Files in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)

IMHO your best bet is to send the file in chunks using HttpModule. These might be of interest:

[Large File Upload Using HttpHandler or HttpModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348554/large-file-upload-using-httphandler-or-httpmodule)

[HttpHandler or HttpModule for file upload, large files, progress indicator?](http://forums.asp.net/t/55127.aspx/1/10)

Best of luck :)